# Identifying the point on a GMAP .net Route that was mouse clicked in C#

Tags: c#, routes, click, mouse, gmap.net

I am developing an application to show the runs and lifts from a skiing holiday.  The input file is the TCX data file saved from by Garmin Fenix 3.

I have successfully plotted the different track segments from the file as routes but now want to be able to correct the start and stop points. To do this I want to be able to select a route from the map and click on the point I want to use as a start or stop point.

I can select the route and access the information on the route but so far I have not been able to identify the position along the route that the mouse was clicked.

I have tried comparing the location that that the mouse was clicked `e.location.X` and `e.location.Y` with the `LocalPoint` data within the route

```
if( e.location.X==route.LocalPoints.x && e.location.Y==route.LocalPoints.y)
{......}
```

but this does not find a corresponding point.

I have also tried with `e.X` and `E.Y` instead of the `.Location` points

Is there a way to directly identify the point on the route that was clicked or the nearest point to the click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure can.

When you are adding your route points you are most likely using something like:

```
overlay.Markers.Add(point);
gMapControl1.UpdateRouteLocalPosition(overlay);
```

The points that you add are directly accessible as markers. Make sure you add the event

```
gMapControl1.OnMarkerClick += new MarkerClick(gMapControl1_OnMarkerClick);
```

Then inside this method you can get the marker that was clicked and change the position as you need to:

```
void gMapControl1_OnMarkerClick(GMapMarker item, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    item.Position = new PointLatLng(...);
}
```

Just make sure you update the route after you change the coordinates. You also need to make sure your markers are enabled for selection.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I was just adding the points as a route.  I can see a way to make it work creating markers for each point.  I may need to play a little with only creating the markers when I need them as the points are generated once per second on the by the GPS.  So in a mornings skiing there are 1000+ points in a run.

Comment: On that note, I am doing something somewhat similar and the easiest way to handle it is to add the start and stop markers in their own layer, then make everything else a route on a different layer. Works great for me.